# How to make the program run in .exe mode explained below

Tags: c#

I just have written a code in C# its a web browser using Visual Studio 2015
How do i make it compiled to .exe file and etc, like chrome mozilla etc.
Help appriciated.

Comment: Click the "Debug"-Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you set up your project correctly in VS, it's Ctrl-Shft-B to compile.  The exe / dll files should end up wherever specified by your Build Output directory. To learn about/change this see [Change Build Output Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165410.aspx).

Comment: Well okay, complied but, `Could not locate the assembly "Awesomium.Core, Version=1.7.4.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e1a0d7c8071a5214". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.`, Also and
`Could not locate the assembly "Awesomium.Windows.Forms, Version=1.7.4.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9bd24830fbe304a0, processorArchitecture=x86". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.`
P.S Already installed the awesomium core too.